# Best practices for sharing third party dependencies with your own dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

My project has a dependency on another project, and I'm using git dependency as follows in the `setup.py` file:

```
setup(
    name="cake",
    version="0.1",
    install_requires=[
        "flan @ git+ssh://git@github.com/terrymcguire/flan.git#egg=flan"
    ]
)
```

Suppose they *both* depend on `pyyaml`.  Is it best practice to include a `"pyyaml==5.1.2"` inside both projects' `setup.py`, `install_requires: ...` (or `requirements.txt` as you prefer), and make sure the versions are the same, or is it recommended to only have `pyyaml` listed as a dependency in the `flan` project, and then inherit the version in the parent project, even though it's then less clear that `pyyaml` is a dependency of the parent project, and if one day I no longer depend on `flan`, I might not notice I may have broken other code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**

> Is it best practice to include a "`pyyaml==5.1.2`" inside both projects' `setup.py`, `install_requires: ...` (or `requirements.txt` as you prefer) [...]?

Only applications should (possibly) *pin* requirements to a specific version. Libraries should restrict to a range of known compatible versions (as accurate as possible).

In general I believe pinning the versions of dependencies in `setup.py` (or `pyproject.toml`) is a bad idea, since those can not be (easily) overruled by the end user, the one ultimately installing the projects (doesn't matter if applications or libraries) and the one who should have the last word on what gets installed. On the other hand it is good practice to give a recommendation of a combination of pinned versions of dependencies that is known to work well (because it has been tested) in the form of a `requirements.txt` file that the end user might opt to use or not (for applications, this doesn't make much sense for libraries).

Read for example [Donald Stufft's article "*setup.py vs requirements.txt*"](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/).

**2.**

> is it recommended to only have pyyaml listed as a dependency in the flan project, and then inherit the version in the parent project, even though it's then less clear that pyyaml is a dependency of the parent project [...]?

The general (obvious) rule is that all projects should list all of their own dependencies and only their own dependencies. Anything else doesn't make any sense (of course there might be exceptions as always).